# Javascript won't save cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using a quick Javascript code (based on a tutorial) to try and create an age screen on a site. However, although the age screen should only pop up once and then be fine for a while, it pops up every refresh. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while(c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if(c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
function checkCookie() {
    var age = getCookie("allowed");
    if (age != true) {
        age = confirm("you must be 18 or older to enter and view the content on this blog");
    }
    if (age == true) {
        setCookie("allowed", age, 7);
    } else if (age == false) {
        //window.location.replace("http://tumblr.com/dashboard");
    }
    return age;
}
</script>
```

I've checked every available online resource and tutorial I can find, but nothing explains why this won't save the cookie properly. If I open the console, it recognizes the site creating the cookie, but gives me undefined values for everything.

If I have the console run the checkCookie() function, it returns the proper value depending on whether I clicked 'OK' or 'Cancel' but it still won't actually save that value into the cookie.

Can *anyone* think of any reason this might be happening?

**UPDATE**

After changing the `age == true` checks from boolean checks into strings, it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is probably being saved. But your getCookie method has a typo in it on like 6 `c.substring(name,length,c.length);`

Instead you should have  `c.substring(name.length,c.length);`

#### Update

Change the following lines in your checkCookie method to

```
if (age) {
    setCookie("allowed", age, 7);
}
```

OR

```
if (age === true) {
    setCookie("allowed", age, 7);
}
```

Once the setCookie is called, refresh the browser and you should be able to see the cookie set.

#### Update 2

`getCookie` returns a string so it should be `age != "true"` and
`confirm` returns a boolean so `age === true` should work

```
var age = getCookie("allowed");
if (age != "true") {
    age = confirm("you must be 18 or older to enter and view the content on this blog");
}
if (age === true) {
    setCookie("allowed", age, 7);
} else if (age == false) {
    //window.location.replace("http://tumblr.com/dashboard");
}
```

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks! I didn't notice that. However, the confirm box still comes up on every refresh, so I'm still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When you read the value you compare it to a boolean when it is infact a string (`"true"==true` is false) - Instead: `if (age == "true") ...`

Comment: I just changed it, but it still both returns the same results and has the same problem.

Comment: I created this account very recently, so I can't post a picture, but in the resources tab of the console, for the cookies on that site, both the name and value are undefined, with the expiration listed as "Session."

Comment: Done... with no results. Neither option seems to change anything; the cookie is still set to undefined and the confirm box still pops up every refresh.

Comment: @Marxilliousus: i tried `if (age != "true")` in line 2 and `if (age === true)`  in line 5 and it worked

Comment: I'm not sure why that worked, but it did! Thank you!

Comment: sure, if it solved your question please mark it an answered. Updated the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

`(typeof age)` is string
so you can either change `age != true` to  `age != 'true'` and the same for other checks or convert it to Boolean like `!!age != true`

Comment: Interestingly enough, this works on my test site, but when I add the code to the actual blog, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do   !!age != true or !!age == true  and for all three of the checks and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference.